# The union of two sets of measure zero, has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis

This is my previous attempt: [Show that the union of two sets of measure zero, has a measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683864/show-that-the-union-of-two-sets-of-measure-zero-has-a-measure-zero)

Need help with my flow of logic, and accuracy.

Proof

Assume $f, g$ be Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$.

$\forall \epsilon>0$

Let $u$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$ and $v$ be the set of discontinuities of $g$.

Since u and v have measure zero, by defintion $\exists I_i = \{I_1,I_2,....\}$ s.t.

$u,v \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(I_i) < \epsilon$

Since $u$ and $v$ are mutually disjoint,

$m(u \cup v) = m(u) + m(v)$

Then for, $u \setminus (u \cap v)), u \cap v \subset m(u \cup v)$

We have $m(u \setminus (u \cap v))) + m(u \cap v) = 0$

By definition, $u\cup v \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(I_i) < \epsilon$

Hence the union of the two sets has measure zero.

Comment: Won't that assume that for any set of measure zero you can find a Riemann(!) integrable function having this set as set of discontinuities?

Comment: Argue directly from what I assume is your definition of measure $0$. If $U$ has measure $0$, then it can be covered by a union of intervals $I_n$ such that the sum of the lengths of the $I_n$ is $\lt \epsilon/2$. Similarly, $V$ can be covered by a union of intervals $J_n$ the sum of whose lengths is $\lt \epsilon/2$. Continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use the definitions here:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of Lebesgue measure zero, so that there are sequences $\left \{ I _k\right \}_{k\in \mathbb N}\ $and $\left \{ J _k\right \}_{k\in \mathbb N}\ $ s.t $A\subseteq \bigcup _k I_k$ and $B\subseteq \bigcup _k J_k$ and s.t $\ \forall \epsilon >0,$

$\sum _k\vert I_k\vert <\epsilon$ and $\sum _k\vert J_k\vert <\epsilon$. Now, since $\left \{ I_k,J_{k'} \right \}_{k,k'}$ is countable, arrange it in some way to obtain a countable sequence $\left \{ I'_n \right \}_n$, which has the desired properties:

$A\cup B\subseteq \bigcup _nI'_n$

and

$\sum _n\vert I'_n\vert <2\epsilon$